# PhoneGap app freezes/locks up after network change when using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, html, xmlhttprequest, phonegap

I have an Adobe PhoneGap app that uses PHP on the backend. After a network change (Like Wifi -> 4G), the app crashes whenever there is a `XMLHttpRequest` (Or communication with the server). If I let the app sit "frozen" for 3 minutes the app then continues to work fine. I am testing on an android phone, with a 'built' .apk.

What I have tried/am doing. This is in my config file

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="*://*api.parse.com/*"/>

And here is what my code looks like that is communication with PHP 

    function getProducts() {
      var url = 'http://www.*.com/*/*/getProducts.php';
      var params = "ID=1" + 

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('GET', url + "?" + params, false);
      xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);

      function processRequest(e) {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = xhr.response;
       }
     }

     xhr.send(params);
    }
```

Has anyone else ran into this problem before?

Here is all plugins I am using

```
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device"/> 
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
```

Edit: It looks as if my app does not go into the function `processRequest`

Edit2: It appears that this bug is android only. I tested it on an Apple iPhone 6 and there isn't an issue. I also changed my `getProducts` function to a `onreadystatechange` type. It now does not lock up the app, but it does not load the php results until I opened/reopened the page 6 times. `XMLHttpRequest.readyState` property returns 1, but does not ever return 2,3 or 4 (until after 6 times).

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall `network-information` plugin.

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.network-information
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information
```

May help.

p.s. Also try to restart all requests if `navigator.connection.type` was changed.
And dont forget, that after Cordova 2.3.0 `navigator.connection.type` was changed to `navigator.connection`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I reinstalled network-information plugin and it did not help. My pages work up until there is php/xmlhttp interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on two other wifi networks and could not replicate the issue. Maybe firewall issues? Or the fact that the PHP file/server was on that wifi network.